# How can I get Total count of parts,count of passed parts and count of failed parts in a single query

Tags: mysql

There is a table with columns Quantity,Date of insertion and Result.

```
Quantity || TIMESTAMP || RESULT
Sample 1 || 2019-01-28 18:21:04 || PASS
Sample 2 || 2019-01-30 18:21:04 || FAIL
```

and so on

How can a single query give total count of parts , count of passed and count of failed GROUPED BY Date only?

Answer (score 0):

Use of multiple sub-queries would be only option of yours if you are using MySQL 5.x.

```
select (select count(*) from Test ) as Total, passed.val, failed.val
from (select count(*) as val, tmstamp from Test where result = 'PASS' group by tmstamp) passed
   , (select count(*) as val, tmstamp from Test where result = 'FAIL' group by tmstamp) failed
WHERE passed.tmstamp = failed.tmstamp;
```

You should look into CTE (Common Table Expression) functionality if you are using MySQL8.

```
WITH Passed as (select count(*) as val, tmstamp from Test where result = 'PASS' group by tmstamp),
Failed as (select count(*) as val, tmstamp from Test where result = 'FAIL' group by tmstamp)
select (select count(*) from Test ) as Total, p.val, f.val
From Passed p
     join Failed f on f.tmstamp = p.tmstamp
```